Keyboard Size in InputMethodService

Hello, I am creating a keyboard with Jetpack Compose, and I want the keyboard to change height and animate at a certain moment. However, when changing the height, the view seems to shift upwards (a white stripe appears), and the icons for closing the keyboard and switching keyboards also move.
